# WPF Submenu ItemsPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, menu

I want to show the menu items in multiple Columns..

I want to use **WrapPanels** for menus

below code works well for first level, but when opening sub menus or sub menus of sub menus ,  its shows as ordinary list.

What can be done to override the default behavior.

note: *I am using `Itemssource` to bind menu items (Objects of my own Class), so i can't give nested Item Styles.*

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}"  BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}">
   ....
   <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Children}"/>
   ....
   <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
         <Setter.Value>
             <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                   <WrapPanel MaxHeight="300" Orientation="Vertical"/>
             </ItemsPanelTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
     ....
</Style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind to any level

```
          <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Children}"/>
                    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <WrapPanel MaxHeight="300" Orientation="Vertical"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
                    <Setter.Value>
                            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Children}"/>
                                <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <WrapPanel MaxHeight="300" Orientation="Vertical"/>
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Children}"/>
                                            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                        <WrapPanel MaxHeight="300" Orientation="Vertical"/>
                                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>   
            </Style>
```

Comment: I have no problem with binding to Children, All Levels have same property called "Children", My problem is not the sub menus are shown using WrapPanel. Instead they are using stack-panel to show the list.

Comment: you can set ItemsPanel for submenu too like updated answer.

Comment: So is it like if i have 10 level of menu bar items, i have to repeat this hierarchy.

Comment: If all your properties will be same, you can have only one style defined in resources without key. It will be applied to all menuitem and submenuitem. Otherwise you will have to define for each level